# How can I stop borders blurring when CSS-transform scaling in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

Take this example using react-pose to animate an element "popping onto the page":
https://codesandbox.io/s/qljpvpowp9
On Firefox, Safari and even IE, the spinner element renders fine:

[image: FF]

but on Chrome 71 the CSS semi-circle (border + border-radius) is blurred beyond recognition:

[image: Chrome]

I understand that this is because Chrome is initially rendering the pixels of the border at the low scale the element initialises with, but how can I get round this? Is there a CSS property I can set to stop this happening in the first place, or a way to trigger a redraw once the scaling animation has finished?

Comment: the first element seems to be fine, when you add a new one it looks bad. Is it the case for you?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yep! ..as that's the one that starts life at scale 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add keyframes for scaling animate:

```
const scaling = keyframes`
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
`;
```

Then change the spinner's animate:

```
animation: ${scaling} 0.5s, ${spin} 1s infinite linear;
```

Forked CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/81pmjjz60

Hope this will help.

Comment: Ah nice! Yes it does! Thank you very much :-D